# CLLocationManager "what if user says no"

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

Two questions:

1. If the user says 'no' what is the best way to handle this?  My app depends on location as I show them how far they are form things (3.8 miles away, .2 miles away, 5 miles away, etc...).
   What has everyone else done when the user says no? Can you get access anyway via the phone, like general city "Dallas, tx"? Maybe I should set them at some random location like Africa so they can't get to data locally, but can still see the features?
2. If they say "no", I am reading you can't ask them again. How would I go about locking down the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement some demo mode and show the user all the wonderful things he is missing, rather than shutting down the UI. You could also hint, that, if he changes his mind, he can always reopen the app, and answer the question with YES.